# Linking OpenCV library in Xcode 4?

Tags: xcode, opencv, xcode4, linker-errors

I've been having trouble compiling my own OpenCV iOS project. I started with a simple command-line app target and I've now added an iOS app target. The problem is that my iOS target produces the following linker error:

> ld: library not found for -lcv
>   collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
>   Command
>   /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin/llvm-g++-4.2
>   failed with exit code 1

I'm not sure where the flag, `-lcv` is coming from, as I haven't set it as any of the settings in my project's "Build Settings". I've downloaded a demo OpenCV iPhone project that compiles perfectly fine, and I've tried to copy the build settings from this project but I can't see what's different!

Thanks very much for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding in the project settings the path exact of the library since : /User/..... 
important: only ONE ""